# Java: How do I detect the format and read the RGB values of each pixel from an image?

Tags: java, image, import, pixel

I have been writing a program for batch image processing. The images come in various formats, but all are either JPEG, TIFF, or PNG. I wrote the following class for storing and accessing pixel data:

```
package imageReader;

import misc.NumberFunctions;

/**
 * A class to store pixel data and provide access to some of the pixel's     basic
 * attributes
 * 
 * @author Thomas
 *
 */
public class Pixel {

    /**
     * The X-coordinate of the pixel The left-most column of the image     is x=0
     */
    private int x;

    /**
     * The Y-coordinate of the pixel The top row of the image is y=0
     */
    private int y;

    /**
     * The red value of the pixel (from 0 to 255)
     */
    private int r;

    /**
     * The green value of the pixel (from 0 to 255)
     */
    private int g;

    /**
     * The blue value of the pixel (from 0 to 255)
     */
    private int b;

    /**
     * The highest color value in the pixel, which determine its brightness
     * (from 0 to 255)
     */
    private int value;

    /**
     * Creates an empty pixel object, setting it to black (0,0,0)
     * 
     * @param x
     *            the x-coordinate of the pixel
     * @param y
     *            the y-coordinate of the pixel
     */
    public Pixel(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = 0;
        this.g = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.setValue();
    }

    /**
     * Get the x-coordinate of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the x-coordinate
     */
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    /**
     * Get the y-coordinate of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the y-coordinate
     */
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    /**
     * Get the red value of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the red value (0 - 255)
     */
    public int getRed() {
        return this.r;
    }

    /**
     * Get the green value of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the green value (0 - 255)
     */
    public int getGreen() {
        return this.g;
    }

    /**
     * Get the blue value of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the blue value (0 - 255)
     */
    public int getBlue() {
        return this.b;
    }

    /**
     * Get the brightness of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the value (0 - 255)
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the brightness of the pixel
     * 
     * @return the value (0 - 100)
     */
    public double getValue100() {
        double value100 = ((double) this.value) / 2.55;
        return value100;
    }

    /**
     * Check if this Pixel object is set to the same location as another
     * 
     * @param otherPixel
     *            the other pixel
     * @return whether they share the same coordinates or not
     */
    public boolean hasSameLocation(Pixel otherPixel) {
        boolean xMatches = (this.getX() == otherPixel.getX());
        boolean yMatches = (this.getY() == otherPixel.getY());
        return (xMatches && yMatches);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if this pixel has the same color as another pixel
     * 
     * @param otherPixel
     *            the other pixel
     * @return whether they share the same color or not
     */
    public boolean hasSameColor(Pixel otherPixel) {
        if (this.getValue() != otherPixel.getValue())
            return false;
        boolean redMatches = (this.getRed() == otherPixel.getRed());
        boolean greenMatches = (this.getGreen() == otherPixel.getGreen());
        boolean blueMatches = (this.getBlue() == otherPixel.getBlue());
        if (redMatches && greenMatches && blueMatches)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * An internal function for finding the brightness value of the pixel
     */
    private void setValue() {
        this.value = NumberFunctions.getMax(r, g, b);
    }
}
```

I would like to import the images (I can already get the paths for all of them) and then record each image's data in a two dimensional array of Pixel objects (Pixel[][]). To do this, I need your guys' help to do three things:

1. Determine the image type and import it
2. Find out the image's dimensions
3. Read the RGB values of each individual pixel

I appreciate any help you guys can give me. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware, that saving an image like this will require 6 times the size of the original image? Not even counting the overhead of a Java object for each pixel.

Comment: Are you deliberately avoiding the use of [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) and [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to import an image given a file name. This can throw an IOException so be mindful of that.

```
String path = "Image1.jpg";
File file = new File(path);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

Image type is not important for this, `ImageIO` will automatically detect it. If you want type after reading use `image.getType()`

The image dimensions can be taken from `BufferedImage`

```
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
```

Pixels can be read with `image.getRGB(int x, int y)` which returns an integer color. You can convert this to `java.awt.color` with the constructor `Color c = new Color(int rgb)` Then it is a simple process to get the channels with `c.getRed()` `c.getGreen()` `c.getBlue(0)`

If I can give you some advice, don't duplicate the data. Instead of building `Pixel`s, just write your methods to get data using the methods above. As other people pointed out, your implementation will take up a lot more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BufferedImage`:

```
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("monkey.jpg")); // TODO actual file
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    // TODO do whatever you want with image, for example get an rgb:
    Color color = new Color(image.getRgb(0,0));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO handle
}
```

By the way, this is ugly code:

```
if (redMatches && greenMatches && blueMatches)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Replace it by:

```
return redMatches && greenMatches && blueMatches;
```